# Invalid calling object in Edge when input change (onChange)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge

Getting error Invalid Calling Object in Edge when changing input in my React application.

Error: `0: Invalid Calling Object` in react-dom.production.min.js

Binded method is handling the onChange. Only thing that happens in that method is this.setState.

I'm using Babel polyfill with IE supported.

No errors in Chrome.

Comment: Is this only in edge or also in Chrome? What would the error in Chrome be and what is the code that produces the error?

Comment: @HMR no errors in Chrome.

Comment: Can you share the code from the component that's calling onChange? Might help figure it out.

Comment: There are many scenarios that may cause this problem, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by webpack devtools of source maps. It was set to eval. Microsoft IE11/Edge are not handling eval() very well.

After I set devtools to source-maps it worked.